# как убрать у фона отступы

Tags: css3, html5

У меня есть код:

```css
.thr-block {
  background: url("img/thr-back.png") no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1198px;
  background-size: 1500px;
  background-position-x: -60px;
  background-origin: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="thr-block"></div>
```

но у фона есть отступы, я уже 2 день пытаюсь убрать, помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У фона нет отступов, но отступы по умолчанию есть у body, а Вы, по всей видимости, их не сбросили.

Вот Ваш пример с отступами:

```css
html {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.thr-block{
  background: url("https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1866711/5d7e1034-d839-4504-83a5-24fb2ea637d6/s1200") no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1198px;
  background-size: 1500px;
  background-position-x: -60px;
  background-origin: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="thr-block"></div>
```

А вот как будет выглядеть, если сбросить отступы по умолчанию:

```css
html {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.thr-block{
  background: url("https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1866711/5d7e1034-d839-4504-83a5-24fb2ea637d6/s1200") no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1198px;
  background-size: 1500px;
  background-position-x: -60px;
  background-origin: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="thr-block"></div>
```

Существуют разные библиотеки типа reset.css, которые нужно использовать для сброса браузерных стилей (если Вы верстаете без использования фреймворков типа Bootstrap - там сбрасывание уже включено).

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто растянуть фон на весь блок.

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: я пробовал не вышло